# How can I get this kind of layout of buttons by getting data from one api in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, api, user-interface, layout

How can I get this kind of layout of buttons when getting data from an API in flutter,,As shown in the picture

[image]

Comment: Can be used SearchDelegate with chip

Comment: I don't want for search ,,I just want that kind of layout of buttons,,they have no link with search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [Chip](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Chip-class.html) widget, and use [Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) to make it group.

Doc example

```dart
Wrap(
  spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
  runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
  children: <Widget>[
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: const Text('AH')),
      label: const Text('Hamilton'),
    ),
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: const Text('ML')),
      label: const Text('Lafayette'),
    ),
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: const Text('HM')),
      label: const Text('Mulligan'),
    ),
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: const Text('JL')),
      label: const Text('Laurens'),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Also try [`ActionChip`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ActionChip-class.html)

Comment: Thank you so much Wrap was the widget , I was looking for ❤️

Comment: Glad to help, explore the links for more